# Converting Polygon to Raster in ArcMap, with a specified spatial extent

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, extents, rasterization

I have a vector/polygon map of UK soil %sand values which is using the British National Grid coordinate system.

I would like to convert this to a raster map with 50m x 50m resolution, with the bottom left hand corner starting at national grid 0,0 (or any number divisible by 50).

When I use the Polygon to Raster tool I am not given an option to change the extent. I have tried changing the extent of my dataframe, but the resulting raster map does not have the same extent as the one I specify.

Does anyone know how to set the extent of exported raster maps?

Answer (score 2):

When you use a geoprocessing tool, you can modify some environment variables by clicking on the "environment" button. This also work for the "polygon to raster tool". One of the environment variable is "processing extent", where you have several choices including "same as Display" or "as specified below". The latter allows you to enter your own extent manually. Note that you can define the environment variables at different levels, which can be useful if you have to repeat the same process several times. See [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/environments/setting-geoprocessing-environment.htm) for more details.

[image]
[image]